# In SQL how to get parent related value by column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I work on SQL Server 2005 and lowest.

I have a SQL Server table structure like below:

```
ID    Name     ParentID
-----------------------
1     Root       NULL
2     Business   1
3     Finance    1
4     Stock      3
```

I want to write a query, when user give input ID=1 then show this output here:

```
ID    Name     ParentName
-------------------------
1     Root      -
2     Business  Root
3     Finance   Root
4     Stock     Finance
```

When user gives input ID=3 then show this output here:

```
ID    Name     ParentName
-------------------------
3     Finance   Root
1     Root      -
4     Stock     Finance
```

When user give input ID=4 then show this output:

```
ID    Name     ParentName
-------------------------
4     Stock     Finance    
3     Finance   Root
1     Root      -
```

Thanks in advance. If have any query plz ask. thanks for all

Comment: What is the logic to display your lists based on that ID?  The only pattern I can see is the input ID being first.

Comment: i have two table base on parent -child relation need to show detail records.sorry i forget to tell about detail table.Hope you understand,Why i need this type of query

Comment: How to get result with out CTE

Comment: Agree on GONeale's point. There is some vague idea though, but it needs clarifying. What would the output be if the input was ID=2?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.Name AS ParentName FROM tableName t1
LEFT JOIN tableName t2 on t1.ID = t2.ParentID
```

Replace `tableName` obviously with your table.
Add `t2.ID` to select list to view match up if you like.

Comment: Doesn't filter by the user input, as requested

Comment: Sorry, true. I will adjust when I have more details.

Comment: User don't know the depth .If depth is one then user can easily use join or union key words to get the value .but user don't know the depth.May be need to use the recursive technique.i don't know how to use recursive technique on sql .

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand exactly how your filter should work. Maybe somebody else could help if they understand.

Comment: plz why not u see the above description.Hope it's not difficult to understand if u spend some time to read my question description.

Comment: It wasn't clear on how your query results should be displayed as you didn't explain that, you just showed the tables. But I can see now you want the parent for each record then on the next result the last parent name to be the start of the next one. Sorry I don't think I can help you devise the query.

Answer (score 0):

These two recursive CTE's (Common Table Expression) will select the hierarchy from a given node on down in your tree, and also from that node up the tree back to the root. Since it's a CTE, it will work in SQL Server 2005 and newer - but *not* in SQL Server 2000, unfortunately.

```
DECLARE @StartID INT 
SET @StartID = 1

;WITH DownHierarchy AS
(
    SELECT ID, Name, ParentID
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    WHERE ID = @StartID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT d.ID, d.Name, d.ParentID
    FROM dbo.YourTable d
    INNER JOIN DownHierarchy h ON d.ParentID = h.ID
),
UpHierarchy AS
(
    SELECT ID, Name, ParentID
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    WHERE ID = @StartID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT d.ID, d.Name, d.ParentID
    FROM dbo.YourTable d
    INNER JOIN UpHierarchy h ON d.ID = h.ParentID
)
SELECT *
FROM DownHierarchy
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM UpHierarchy
```

Setting `@StartID = 1` will give you this output:

```
ID  Name    ParentID
 1  Root      NULL
 2  Business  1
 3  Finance   1
 4  Stock     3
```

Setting `@StartID = 3` will give you this output:

```
ID  Name     ParentID
 1  Root     NULL
 3  Finance   1
 4  Stock     3
```

Comment: Run the above syntax show those errors.Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 8
Must declare the variable '@data'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 14
Must declare the variable '@data'.

Comment: @shamim: replace `@data` / `dbo.YourTable` with your table name

Comment: After set the table name show the bellow error:  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Line 15: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: @Shamim: are you trying this on SQL Server **2000** or **2005** ?? This will **NOT** work on SQL Server 2000 - only on 2005....

Comment: i use server 2005 .But i can not use the above syntax,above syntax show me the error  ....Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Line 15: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: @shamim: this must work on SQL Server 2005.... you must have a typo or something in your SQL. Have you paid attention to the leading semicolon before the `WITH` ??

Answer (score 0):

Here's modification to marc_s' answer:

```
  Declare @data table
(ID bigint identity(1,1)   ,Name varchar(100),    ParentID bigint)

Insert into @data SELECT 'Root',NULL
Insert into @data SELECT 'Business',1
Insert into @data SELECT 'Finance',1
Insert into @data SELECT 'Stock',3


DECLARE @StartID INT 
SET @StartID = 3

;WITH DownHierarchy AS
(
    SELECT ID, Name, ParentID
    FROM @data
    WHERE ID = @StartID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT d.ID, d.Name, d.ParentID
    FROM @data d
    INNER JOIN DownHierarchy h ON d.ParentID = h.ID
),
UpHierarchy AS
(
    SELECT ID, Name, ParentID
    FROM @data
    WHERE ID = @StartID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT d.ID, d.Name, d.ParentID
    FROM @data d
    INNER JOIN UpHierarchy h ON d.ID = h.ParentID
)
SELECT *
FROM DownHierarchy
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM UpHierarchy
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar answer - but having built it I want to post it ;)

```
declare @Data table (
    ID int not null,
    Name varchar(50) not null,
    ParentID int null
);

insert into @Data
select  1, 'Root', null
union select 2, 'Business', 1
union select 3, 'Finance', 1
union select 4, 'Stock', 3;

declare @UserInput int;
set @UserInput = 4;

with cParents as (
    select  d.ID, d.Name, d.ParentID
    from    @Data d
    where   d.ID = @UserInput
    union all
    select  d.ID, d.Name, d.ParentID
    from    cParents c
    inner join @Data d
        on  d.ID = c.ParentID
),
cChildren as (
    select  d.ID, d.Name, d.ParentID
    from    @Data d
    where   d.ID = @UserInput
    union all
    select  d.ID, d.Name, d.ParentID
    from    cChildren c
    inner join @Data d
        on  d.ParentID = c.ID
)
select  RecordType='self', d.ID, d.Name, ParentName=isnull(p.Name,'')
from    @Data d
left join @Data p
    on  p.ID = d.ParentID
where   d.ID = @UserInput

union all

select  RecordType='parents', d.ID, d.Name, ParentName=isnull(p.Name,'')
from    cParents d
left join @Data p
    on  p.ID = d.ParentID
where   d.ID <> @UserInput

union all

select  RecordType='children', d.ID, d.Name, ParentName=isnull(p.Name,'')
from    cChildren d
left join @Data p
    on  p.ID = d.ParentID
where   d.ID <> @UserInput;
```

@Data represent the sample data, @UserInput is the input variable.
I added a RecordType to clarify the meaning of the record parts.
It is tested on SQL Server 2008 and should work on 2005 - but not on 2000.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spGetParent, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spGetParent, Line 20
Line 20: Incorrect syntax near ','.